# how to set an a href inside another a href

Tags: html, href, markup

i have the page "list.php" where my php script show the list of the records stored in a mysql table, when the user click on the record should go on the page "detail.php" and see all the details.

```
<a class='box' href='detail.php'>
<img src='img.gif' width='60' height='60' alt='' />
<span class='title'>$title</span><br>
<span class='text'>$text</span>
</a>
```

the code above work, but then i cannot add a second "a href" inside the first, for example:

```
<a class='box' href='detail.php'>
<img src='img.gif' width='60' height='60' alt='' />
  <a class='right' href='page2.php'>delete</a>
<span class='title'>$title</span><br>
<span class='text'>$text</span>
</a>
```

so i've try to use a "div" instead of the "a href", like this:

```
  <div class='box' style='cursor:pointer' onClick='location='detail.php'>
<img src='img.gif' width='60' height='60' alt='' />
  <a class='right' href='page2.php'>delete</a>
<span class='title'>$title</span><br>
<span class='text'>$text</span>
</div>
```

but the "onClick='location='page.php'" inside the "div" don't work, any workaround?

Comment: you need `onclick="window.location='detail.php';"`

Comment: You've closed your `onclick=''` prematurely when you've opened another `='detail.php'` inside. Can't do that. Enclose `''` inside `""` or vice versa.

Comment: Sure, sorry! but the syntax is correct? should i use the "div" with onclick? then google can follow these links?

Comment: Yes, syntax is correct. I would use `<div>` with onclick as the parent. Google will not follow that syntax, so if that is of importance, you can wrap your `<img/>` like: `<a href="detail.php"><img src.../></a>` which will give Google a link to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your nested a inside an object tag.

```
<a class='box' href='detail.php'>
<img src='img.gif' width='60' height='60' alt='' />
  <object><a class='right' href='page2.php'>delete</a></object>
<span class='title'>$title</span><br>
<span class='text'>$text</span>
</a>
```